in long texts,keyboard is move up and the end of text disapeared under the keyboard
I have a jetpack compose android screen include two outlinedTextField.but when user type a long text in a OutlinedTextField in jetpack comopse android (Code Below), keyboard is move up and the end of text disapeared behind the phone keyboard. anyone can guide me?
`@Composable
fun TipDescription(value: String = "", onValueChange: (String) -> Unit = {}) {
val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(fraction = 0.97f)
        .wrapContentHeight(),
    textStyle = TextStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Justify),
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    prefix = { Text(text = "Description : ") },
    keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Done),
    keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(onDone = {
        focusManager.moveFocus(focusDirection = FocusDirection.Down)
        focusManager.clearFocus()
        onValueChange(value)
    }),
    colors = inputTextFieldColors()
)

}`
(https://i.sstatic.net/2ek4D2M6.png)
I tryed to use keyboard actions and keyboardOptions property to handle this but dont successfully

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
